# Is there a way to calculate the 2nd derivative of data without first calculating the first derivative?

Tags: python, matlab, c++11, derivative

I'm trying to avoid rounding error with the gradient function in MATLAB. In MATLAB, or any other code base, is it possible to directly calculate the 2nd derivative from x and y values, and avoid truncation error associated with taking the derivative of a derivative?

Comment: Isn't the laplacian what you can use? From memory, a laplacian operator exists in matlab

Comment: @MatinaG The Laplacian takes the derivative with respect to rows and columns. I just want to differentiate pressure with respect to density. Each column is a different isotherm that I do not want to differentiate between. I tried the Laplacian first and it gave me drastically different results that just using the gradient method twice. Using the gradient method twice is "correct," whereas the Laplacian gives me a continuously decreasing function (which is wrong). I realized it did this because it was taking the second derivative wrt x and y.

Comment: You can fit a spline to the data first (which is also very useful for noisy data) and then calculate the second derivative. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline.html https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/13812-splinefit

Answer (score 0):

If your data has uniform spacing, finite difference methods are a great way to get the 2nd derivative.

[This Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference_coefficient) has a list of coefficients for computing different derivatives with different orders of accuracy.

Comment: It MATLAB the gradient method used the central difference method with 16 digits. Isn't this about as accurate as it gets? I just have to use the gradient method twice to get the second derivative.

Comment: I doubt the 16 digits part will give you any trouble. If your (second) derivative looks very noisy, it's probably due to using a low order approximation. I'd guess that MATLAB uses the second order accuracy method, which is enough for most purposes. If it's not good enough for you, try one of the higher order methods.

Comment: @Ben I checked the MATLAB documentation. The MATLAB gradient method corresponds with the Wikipedia "Derivative=1, Accuracy=2" method. Applying this twice is equivalent with the Wikipedia "Derivative=2, Accuracy=2" method.
"Derivative=2, Accuracy=4" or higher accuracies are still possibilities.

Comment: Im MATLAB, can I change the accuracy ?

Comment: @Ben "To how many sig figs is the second order accuracy?"
That's not a question I can answer for you. It depends heavily on your function and finite difference interval.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184050/discussion-between-jonathan-chiang-and-ben).

Comment: I don;t understand, you requested to move it to chat, but are not responding?

Comment: Sorry, I can't access chat on my current network. I'm blocked by a firewall.

Comment: Is there a way in MATLAB to change the accuracy?

Comment: @Ben To my knowledge, no you can't change the accuracy of the built-in MATLAB gradient function. I would recommend that you program your own finite difference derivative function.

Comment: Note that the name accuracy is misleading. Is a smoothing operation, you dont increase the accuracy, you just smooth the derivative, using larger chunck of the data. It may be more accurate for some sort of specific noisy data, but you also may lose accuracy for oversmoothing

Comment: So what does second order accuracy mean?